# Not able to import pandas in python 2.7.14 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ubuntu-16.04

Not able to work on pandas in python 2.7.14 ubuntu 16.02.
When I try to install pandas module using

```
pip install pandas
```

It shows requirement already satisfied.
If we try to import in python program, it gives

***no module named numpy.***

I tried uninstalling pandas package, it but didn't work for me.
It is working fine with python 2.7.12.
But I want it to be working in latest version of python 2.7

***I used below commands to upgrade default python 2.7.12 in ubuntu to python 2.7.14***

Download using the following command:

```
    version=2.7.14
    cd ~/Downloads/
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz
```

Extract and go to the directory:

```
tar -xvf Python-$version.tgz
cd Python-$version
```

Now, install using the command you just tried, using checkinstall instead to make it easier to uninstall if needed:

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

***Is there anything wrong in upgrading python version?***

Comment: Well, is `numpy` already satisfied? Also, not clear which Python version's `pip` you are using

Comment: yes. If I try to install numpy, it gives requirement satisfied

Comment: The you are not running the correct Python exectuable

Comment: Important note: pandas 0.24.x releases will be the last to support Python 2!
[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html)

Answer (score 0):

First install numpy then pandas:

```
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Please don't use `sudo pip install`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion cricket_007 you can remove sudo also

Answer (score 0):

> I used below commands to upgrade default python 2.7.12 in ubuntu to python 2.7.14

First, any new Python development should target Python 3.

Second, you can't "upgrade" or "overwrite" the system Python. Nor should you try for many reasons, as the OS depends on that version for internal tasks. If you could upgrade, then you should use `apt-get upgrade`, as recommended.

You downloaded a completely separate version, and you seem to not have placed in on your `PATH` to be used.

For example, if you don't see something like this, then it's not setup correctly.

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/user/Downloads/Python-2.7.14/bin/python'
```

You should use `apt-get` when possible. Personally, I use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), and it'll correctly update your `~/.bashrc` with the version of Python you choose.

But the instructions I see to compile from source say

```
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make altinstall
$ python2.7
>>> # run commands
```

And if you want to install packages from that, you need to do

```
$ python2.7 -m pip install pandas
```

Or

```
$ pip2.7 install pandas
```

Comment: Then I would definitely recommend trying pyenv

Comment: Plenty of documentation there to be read. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-install

Comment: I feel like you didn't read all the documentation. It is not a built in Ubuntu command. You have to install it

Comment: I think you still need to set it as active `pyenv global 2.7.14`

Comment: And you'll want to double check the PATH is setup correctly. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#how-it-works

Comment: Looks like it. Now try installing pandas from pip, then import it in the Python interpreter

Comment: Brand new terminal, or existing one? If your PATH was correct (see section about shims), then that shouldn't happen